# using PHP to edit xml - insert after last

Tags: php, xml, insertafter

So i have this code that is generated mostly by answers for questions asked here.
I want to add a new  after the last one existing.
this is my xml code example (with a lot of Placemarks):

```
 <Folder>
  <Placemark>
    <name><![CDATA[scscsc]]></name>
    <description><![CDATA[Description:ascasc<c,ascascasc<br>]]></description>
    <styleUrl>#placemark-brown</styleUrl>
    <ExtendedData>
    </ExtendedData>
    <Point>
      <coordinates>24.069631625000056,-23.784080251008078,0</coordinates>
    </Point>
   </Placemark>
 </Folder>
```

what i currently have in php is to insert the new one before the last one, and i want it after the last one.
php code:

```
    // find the Folder tag
$root = $xmldoc->getElementsByTagName('Folder')->item(0);

// create the <placemark> tag
$placemark = $xmldoc->createElement('Placemark');

// add the placemark tag After the last element in the <Folder> tag
$root->insertBefore( $placemark, $root->lastChild );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if I'm missing what you mean, but it worked as expected for me?

Looking at the [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/domnode.insertbefore.php) "The reference node. If not supplied, newnode is appended to the children."

So, although it was appending for me anyway, maybe just omit the second parameter?

```
$root->insertBefore( $placemark );
```

(Saved your xml into file.xml)

```
$xmldoc = new DOMDocument();
$xmldoc->load("file.xml");

// find the Folder tag
$root = $xmldoc->getElementsByTagName('Folder')->item(0);

// create the <placemark> tag
$placemark = $xmldoc->createElement('Placemark');

// add the placemark tag After the last element in the <Folder> tag
$root->insertBefore( $placemark );

$xmldoc->save('file.xml', LIBXML_NOEMPTYTAG);
```

Which output the following

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <Folder>
    <Placemark>
        <name><![CDATA[scscsc]]></name>
        <description><![CDATA[Description:ascasc<c,ascascasc<br>]]></description>
        <styleUrl>#placemark-brown</styleUrl>
        <ExtendedData>
        </ExtendedData>
        <Point>
        <coordinates>24.069631625000056,-23.784080251008078,0</coordinates>
        </Point>
    </Placemark>
    <Placemark></Placemark>
    </Folder>
```

Comment: Thank you!
So simple.. exactly what i needed.